# Sinch Libarary Increasing Size of Android APK

Tags: android, sinch

Inclusion of Sinch Library in Existing Android App , increases size of final apk. We found it is the .so file that are very large and contributing to increased size of apk. Please provide a way if some one knows through which size of .so can be reduced and then it can be used in Android Application, As a result final apk size would be reduced.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

all code we have in there needs to be in there. The only think you could do is to makes sliced builds for each Architecture

Answer (score 1):

> Inclusion of Sinch Library in Existing Android App , increases size of final apk.

No surprise. All libs you include in your project becomes part of your project (statically linked).

Comment: Great answer ... This is not a surprise ... But definitely this discourages people developing chat applications to use sinch lib. Thanks